# How to Properly Configure Rails 4.1 Enums in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, activeadmin

I've got a Rails 4.1 app in which I use an enum to represent the privacy level of an object.

In my schema:

```
t.integer "privacy_level", default: 0
```

In my model:

```
enum privacy_level: { privacy_private: 0, privacy_trusted: 1, privacy_public: 2 }
```

In my ActiveAdmin register file:

```
index do
  column :privacy_level
  default_actions
end

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Edit My Model" do
    f.input :privacy_level
  end
  f.actions
end
```

On the ActiveAdmin index page, it works great. The privacy level of each object shows up as "privacy_private", "privacy_trusted", and "privacy_public".

However, when I try to edit an object, the input type is a number box with up and down arrows which allow me to put any integer in, regardless of whether or not the integer is a valid privacy level (even negative values).

What I would like to see is a dropdown (select) input with the three enumerated string values I defined in my model.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Building off of Jack's answer, here's what worked for me.  Say your ActiveRecord model is `Tweets`:

```
f.input :privacy_level, as: :select, collection: Tweet.privacy_levels.keys
```

Key things to note here:

- your ActiveRecord has a useful dictionary (available at enum_name.pluralize) of enum keys to values.
- using strings (and ignoring the underlying integer representation) makes it easier to write to the enum value.

Comment: This is the right answer. I didn't notice the plural (levels) at first.

Comment: :include_blank => false would help in addition

Comment: And remember to permit the param in your admin definition :)

Comment: It does not work for me, it throws "'1' is not a valid (attribute name)"

Answer (score 41):

In order to use enums in ActiveAdmin's filters use:

```
filter :level, as: :select, collection: Model.levels
```

assuming an `enum` attribute named `level`

This will make sure to actually put the integer value in the query and not the key name.

Answer (score 7):

do this:

```
f.input :privacy_level, :as => :select, :collection =>  privacy_level.keys.to_a
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I can set privacy level in the console with my_model.privacy_level = "privacy_public". It would make sense that I can use a select box with strings to set the privacy level. Thanks!

Comment: you welcome, glad to help, i have upvoted your question so u can get the point, please do same for me, thanks