# Enum selection in ActiveAdmin for a Engine Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, activeadmin

I continue to get a `undefined method` error when attempting to get the ActiveAdmin form to use a selection box based of the keys for an enum properties for an object. Following the suggested method on stack overflow to [configure active admin forms for enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414880/how-to-properly-configure-rails-4-1-enums-in-activeadmin)  seems to get me half way there although the engine aspect of my object seems to make the enum attribute through the `NoMethodError` exception.

```
 #/lib/book_store/admin/books
 if defined?(ActiveAdmin)
  ActiveAdmin.register  BookStore::Book, as: 'Book' do
    # customize your resource here
    form do |f|
      f.semantic_errors # shows errors on :base
      f.inputs   do
        f.input :cover_type, as: :select, collection:  BookStore::Book.cover_type.keys
      end
      f.actions         # adds the 'Submit' and 'Cancel' buttons
    end
    permit_params :name, :lead, :excerpt, :description, :price, :slug, :cover_type, :num_pages, :size, :cover_image, :author, :author_id, :category
  end
end



#app/models/book_store/book.rb
module BookStore
  class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    belongs_to :category
    enum cover_type: [:soft, :hard]
  end
end
```

gets the following error

```
undefined method `cover_type' for #<Class:0x007fe685217af0>
```

here is the full [stack trace](https://gist.github.com/cdesch/b4881763516bde3697bf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `cover_type` should be pluralized.

```rb
f.input :cover_type, as: :select, collection:  BookStore::Book.cover_types.keys
```

Comment: Yes, thats correct. It is an easy item to overlook. *Face Palm*

Answer (score 2):

Almost a related answer...

You can use [enumerize gem](https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize) and  [activeadmin addons](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/enum_integration.md) to handle enumerations nicely.